# Changing the interface of a IPV6 route on AIX

Tags: ipv6, route, aix

My current IPV6 routing talbe:

```
Route Tree for Protocol Family 24 (Internet v6):
::/96              0.0.0.0           UC        0         0 sit0     -      -   =>
default            link#2            UC        0         0 en0      -      -   
::1%1              ::1%1             UH        0       127 lo0      -      -   
ef80::/64          link#4            UC        0         0 en1      -      -   =>
ef80::/64          link#5            UC        0         0 en2      -      -   
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b46                   UHLWl     0         1 lo0      -      -   
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b47 ee:c6:7f:84:98:3  UHLW      1       321 en2      -      -   
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b92                   UHLWl     0         2 lo0      -      -   
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b93 ee:c6:7f:84:98:4  UHLW      1       318 en1      -      -   
fe80::/64          link#2            UCX     143         0 en0      -      -   
fe80::ecc6:77ff:fe25:6402                   UHXLWl    0         1 lo0      -      -   
ff01::%1/16        ::1               U         0         8 lo0      -      -   
ff02::/16          fe80::ecc6:77ff:fe25:6402 U         0        37 en0      -      -   
ff05::1:12bc       link#2            UHLW      2         8 en0      -      -   
ff11::%1/16        ::1               U         0         0 lo0      -      -   
ff12::/16          fe80::ecc6:77ff:fe25:6402 U         0         0 en0      -      -
```

I need to switch the interfaces of these two routes:

```
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b47 ee:c6:7f:84:98:3  UHLW      1       321 en2
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b93 ee:c6:7f:84:98:4  UHLW      1       318 en1
```

to make it look like:

```
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b47 ee:c6:7f:84:98:3  UHLW      1       321 en1
ef80::21a:64ff:fe92:1b93 ee:c6:7f:84:98:4  UHLW      1       318 en2
```

What's the prefered way to do this on AIX?

P.S.

Have tried using the `smitty tcpip` utility to remove an IPV6 route first and then add one with the expected interface configured. But no good, smitty told that `ee:c6:7f:84:98:3` is a unknow gateway.

Comment: Are you actually using addresses out of the reserved e000::/4  prefix?  Made up examples are more obvious if you use documentation prefix. For site local addresses, unique local address is better.